# Update SQL Server Pivot with new month's data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, pivot

I have a pivot table in SQL server which I created with a query. The columns are months, and the rows are by Customer IDs, with the values in the pivot being sums of their subscription amounts for each month. I'd like to be able to update this every month with the new data for that month, but I'm not sure how to do this short of completely re-creating the table.

Is there a way to create a new column (for the new month) and use UPDATE to populate it with the summed subscription amounts by customer?

This is my query that created the table:

```
SELECT * INTO [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[Pivot_Results] FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data] 
PIVOT (SUM([Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data].[Subscription Amount])
FOR filtered_data.[Month]
IN([2013-01-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-02-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-03-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-04-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-05-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-06-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-07-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-08-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-09-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-10-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-11-01 00:00:00.00],[2013-12-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-01-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-02-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-03-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-04-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-05-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-06-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-07-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-08-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-09-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-10-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-11-01 00:00:00.00],[2014-12-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-01-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-02-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-03-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-04-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-05-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-06-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-07-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-08-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-09-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-10-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-11-01 00:00:00.00],[2015-12-01 00:00:00.00],[2016-01-01 00:00:00.00]))
AS PVT;
```

Comment: Google `Dynamic PIVOT in SQL Server`

Comment: if you need to add a column to the table every month, you should probably think about a different database design.. If you know how to pivot data, then just add a new row to a normalized table and pivot it when you need it.  At that point you would want to google `Dynamic PIVOT in SQL Server`